# Find the probability of selecting an ordered pair from set $S$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Define $S=\left\{ \left( a,b\right) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \mid  a\leq 10,b\leq 10\right\}$ , 
randomly choose an ordered pair from set $S$.
Find the probability that makes $\dfrac {a}{b}+\dfrac {a^{2}}{b^{2}}+\dfrac {a^{3}}{b^{3}}+\ldots +\dfrac {a^{n}}{b^{n}}+\ldots$ be a convergent series and sum of this infinite series be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the series to be convergent we need $a<b$.  Let $k=b-a$.  Then the sum of the series is $a/k$; for this to be an integer we need $k\mid a$.  Also, we need $1\le k\le10-a$.  So the possibilities are
$$\eqalign{
  &a=1\,,\quad k=1\cr
  &a=2\,,\quad k=1,2\cr
  &a=3\,,\quad k=1,3\cr
  &a=4\,,\quad k=1,2,4\cr
  &a=5\,,\quad k=1,5\cr
  &a=6\,,\quad k=1,2,3\cr
  &a=7\,,\quad k=1\cr
  &a=8\,,\quad k=1,2\cr
  &a=9\,,\quad k=1\,.\cr}$$
The probability is $\frac{17}{100}$.